# Using Subscribing Handler Interface when Serialize te modify parameters in symfony

Tags: symfony, service

I have a REST API and have an Entity `User`with field called Avatar, in DB I save name XXXX.jpg but when I return I want to add a url in this field Avatar, for example `www.mylink.com/XXXX.jpg`.

I'm trying with a service implements `SubscribingHandlerInterface`but I don't know how I can use it.

I have this method in this service:

```
class UrlManager implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
{

public static function getSubscribingMethods()
{
    return array(
           array(
               'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
               'format' => 'json',
               'type' => 'AppBundle/Entity/User',
               'method' => 'serializeUrlAvatar',
           ),
       );

}

    public function serializeUrlAvatar(User $user)
{
    $url = 'www.mylink.com';
    return array(
        "avatar" => $url . $user->getAvatar()
    );
}
}
```

but how can I call this service to modify url when I serialize.
Now I do this:

```
$_format = 'json';
$json = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($user, $_format);
        return new Response($json, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/' . $_format]);
```

In `service.yml`:

```
    app.url_converter_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\UrlManager
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
```

**Update**
In my controller I call this function like this:

```
        $result = $this->get('app.url_converter_service')->serializeUrlAvatar($user);
        $json = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($result, $_format);
        return new Response($json, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/' . $_format]);
```

So my question is, exists a way to remove the first line and serialize correctly (add the url) when I serialize?

Comment: seems you're missing the implementation of `serializeUrlAvatar` - where is it? because in it you simply change the data array and return it, done

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry, I edit the question.

Comment: so what is the result of your `$json`?

Comment: Ooh, I had an error that I didn't see.
Now my return is correctly, i have a `json` with my parameters, but I call the service correctly in the controller like this? 
`$result = $this->get('app.url_converter_service')->serializeUrlAvatar($user);`
So the function in my service called `getSubscribingMethods`, what is it for?

Comment: if it's correctly configured and implemented you don't have to call it at all, it will be called by the framework as you 'subscribed' to it. what is the result of `$json` now?

Comment: Okey, now my result is this:
`{
  "avatar": "www.mylink.com/A_1493022795.png"
}`
So it's correctly now. Thanks

Comment: so what was your issue? at least update your question so that others might be able to learn from it as well.

Comment: My issue is, if I have the class `UrlManager`, I don't want use `$result = $this->get('app.url_converter_service')->serializeUrlAvatar(‌​$user);` in my Controller.
Exists a way to do it when I serialize in my Controller return?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your service like this?

```
# app/config/services.yml
avatar_url_handler:
    class: YourBundle\Serializer\Handler\AvatarUrlHandler
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
```

Comment: Yes, I have in `service.yml` 

    app.url_converter_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\UrlManager
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I create a service which implements `EventSubscriberInterface` like this:

```
class UserSerializeHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

private $user_uploads;

public function __construct($user_uploads){
$this->user_uploads = $user_uploads;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
                'class' => User::class,
                'method' => 'onPreSerializeUser'
            ));

}

public function onPreSerializeUser(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getObject();

        $avatar = $user->getAvatar();
        $user->setAvatar($this->user_uploads . "/" . $avatar);
}


}
```

In `service.yml`:

```
 app.serializer_user_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\UserSerializeHandler
    arguments: ['%user_uploads%']
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

I have `user_uploads` in `parameters.yml` like this:

```
user_uploads: 'https://myUrl.com'
```

And in any Controller that I serialize a User, I add the url in the Avatar paramter.

```
$json = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($user, $_format);
return new Response($json, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/' . $_format]);
```